# conditional redirect different layout angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have two layouts in my project. One is Basiclayout and another one is Locationlayout. When a user visits the website for the first time he is in Basiclayout, but when he is giving his location then the layout will be Locationlayout. How can I redirect in my app-routing.module.ts file base on this condition?

Code snippet for my app-routing.module.ts:-

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { 
    path: '',
    component: BasiclayoutComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '',
    component: LocationlayoutComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Can anyone please give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { 
    path: '',
    component: BasiclayoutComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

    ]
  },
  { 
    path: 'location',
    component: LocationlayoutComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

    ]
  }
];
```

Basic Home: http://localhost:4200/home
Location Home: http://localhost:4200/location/home